# getting " cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted " error even after clearing the browser cache

Tags: owasp

I am using OWASP to prevent information leakage on my application. But this not working properly as expected.

I logged in to my application and done some random clicks on the tabs in the application. Then I cleared the web browser  history and cookies .When I click on any tab after  this I will get an pop up screen by saying the session got expired please login again and it redirects me to the login screen when I click on the “ok” button (Till this it worked fine ) . But when I login again and clicking on the tab that used in the last session after deleting the cookies, I get the error “cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack ...” (this is something weird).  If am Clicking on any other tabs I am not getting any error and it works fine

this is a snippet of my OWASP.properties file :-

```properties
#org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Empty=org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Empty
org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Log=org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Log
org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Log.Message=potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted (user:%user%, ip:%remote_ip%, uri:%request_uri%, error:%exception_message%)
#org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Invalidate=org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Invalidate
org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Redirect=org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Redirect
org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Redirect.Page=/ourUI/csrfError.jsp
#org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Redirect.Page=/OLDUI/error/error.jsp
#org.owasp.csrfguard.action.RequestAttribute=org.owasp.csrfguard.action.RequestAttribute
#org.owasp.csrfguard.action.RequestAttribute.AttributeName=errMsg
org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Rotate=org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Rotate
#org.owasp.csrfguard.action.SessionAttribute=org.owasp.csrfguard.action.SessionAttribute
#org.owasp.csrfguard.action.SessionAttribute.AttributeName=Owasp_CsrfGuard_Exception_Key
```

I have uncommented the following line and checked
    org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Invalidate=org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Invalidate

This time I got the error when I click first time on the tab which I have used in last session (followed the same procedure as above) Second time onwards it worked fine. Can anyone please help to find why this error I am getting? Do I need to make any other changes on this file?

Comment: Why is non-code indented as code?